Audit4j revision in separate files
I am using audit4j library in Java for audit messages.
I want to write audit message to separate file in two different files.
For example: revision from A flow to go to a.audit file revision from B flow to go b.audit.
Is this possible with audit4j or I need to implement some other logging library ?
